# (beginner) C++ inheritance in constructor and methods using a Java example as starting point

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I am learning c++ inheritance and I come from Java. To train, I made a small java example and tried to convert it to c++ but my c++ implementations has many problems.

This is my interface IShape.java. It represents the abstraction of a Shape.

```
public interface IShape {
    public void draw();
}
```

And this  is my Triangle.java that implements Shape.

```
public class Triangle implements IShape{
    @Override
    public void draw() {
        //draw code
    }
}
```

And now the Main.java:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IShape someShape = new Triangle();
        someShape.draw();
    }
}
```

Everything works nice and dandy in java, but my c++ version is doesn't even compile :S
This is my IShape.h c++ file. It is supposed to be like the IShape.java interface.

```
#ifndef ISHAPE_H_
#define ISHAPE_H_

class IShape{

public:
    virtual void draw() = 0;

    //must have this because of compiler
    virtual ~IShape();
private:
    //an awesome thing in c++ is that I can also define private methods for my children to implement!
    virtual int compute_point() = 0;
};

#endif
```

And now my Triangle.cpp file:

```
#include "IShape.h"

class Triangle: public IShape {

protected:
    int max_size;

public:
    Triangle(){
        max_size = 255;//This triangle has a limited max size!
    }

    void draw() {
        //implementation code here
    }

private:
    int compute_point() {
        //implementation code here
    }
};
```

And now to finish, my c++ main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "IShape.h"
#include "Triangle.cpp"

using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char *argv[]){

    IShape myShape = Triangle();
    myShape.draw();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

How ever I have errors in my c++ main. Because I have several problems, I will try to enumerate them:

1. It tells me that "mySHape" is abstract, when it is not because I implemented it in triangle class!
2. I cannot call "myShape.draw()" even if I fix the first error
3. My friend says I should never include a cpp file. But if I do not include triangle, how will my Main.cpp know it exists?
4. Is there a better way to port this example in C++? Or am I being too much "java-ed"?

I have read several links and tutorials about c++, and each one teaches me something in a different way, thus I end up with many definitions and a little bit confused. I also searched StackOverflow but the posts I found didn't help me, they usually refer to more complex questions.

What am I doing wrong and what tips can you provide to improve my code style?
Also, sorry for the wall of text, I am trying hard to explain myself and not get down-voted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, in order to achieve polymorphism you have to use **pointers** or **references**. Objects with automatic storage would get sliced, and in your case, not even instantiated. In fact, this instruction:

```
IShape myShape = Triangle();
```

Will try to instantiate an object of type `IShape` and assign a temporary `Triangle` object to it. Definitely not what you want. This, on the other hand, does the work:

```
IShape* myShape = new Triangle(); // Using 
// ...
delete myShape;
```

However, in Modern C++, it is usually a good idea to use *smart* pointers. Try rewriting your `main()` function this way:

```
#include <memory> // For std::shared_ptr<>

int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::shared_ptr<IShape> myShape = std::make_shared<Triangle>();
    myShape->draw();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Also notice, that you have virtual a destructor for which you provide no definition:

```
virtual ~IShape();
```

You should provide one. The simplest way is to inline an empty body this way:

```
virtual ~IShape() { }
```

Comment: When I use pointers, my c++ IShape has a compile error of "undefined reference to vtable". What does it mean?

Comment: "In C++, in order to achieve polymorphism you have to use pointers". *pointers or references.

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix: That's because you have a virtual constructor without a body (see the last part of my answer)

Comment: virtual **de**-structor... constructors are NEVER virtual.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Pardon? Where did I write virtual constructor?

Comment: @AndyProwl in one of the comments

Comment: @juanchopanza: Ooh, that was a bad lapsus. I meant writing destructor.

Comment: Thanks! Should I use shared_ptr or unique_ptr as suggested by another user? Which is better and why? (Or is this a question for another post?)

Comment: @BenVoigt: I see, but can't edit the comment anymore. That's right, I meant to write destructor.

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix: It's a separate question I believe, and the answer depends on the kind of ownership you want to establish for the pointed object

Comment: Just to be clear, if I use a smart pointer, I won't have to use "delete" after right?

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix: Yes, exactly. Smart pointers take care to delete the pointed object when they go out of scope (to be precise: "when they go out of scope and they believe that they are the only smart pointer left which points to that object"). Explanations would require more words than would fit in a comment, so if you need any, I suggest you to post another question ;)

Answer (score 1):

`IShape myShape = Triangle();` This is attempting to create an `IShape` instance and assigning it to a Triangle. `IShape` is abstract as you know, so we can't do this.

What you want is a pointer.

`IShape* myShape = new Triangle();`

Also replace:

`virtual ~IShape();` with `virtual ~IShape() {}`

Comment: When I use pointers, my c++ IShape has a compile error of "undefined reference to vtable". What does it mean?

Comment: You have two error. `compute_point()` should be `protected` just like in java, not `private`.

Comment: @Flame: It's probably because you have not defined `IShape::~IShape` anywhere.

Comment: @andre: Not necessarily.  If `compute_point` is only called from other `IShape` members, `private` is fine.  And many experts actually recommend using private visibility of virtual functions.

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix No, there is no need for `compute_point()` to be protected. In fact, I think it *should* be private. On the other hand, you have to implement the destructor. You should at least give your base class a n empty destructor body.

Comment: @juanchopanza: If it is only called by `IShape` members, it can be private.  I don't think that's the case in his design, however, since `IShape` has no non-trivial member implementations.

Answer (score 1):

It all stems from the fact that you are trying to instantiate an `IShape` *object* here:

```
IShape myShape = ...;
```

This is independent of whatever is on the RHS. The compiler tells you why you cannot do it. You need an `IShape` pointer (or smart pointer if you are using dynamic allocation). In this example, we use automatic storage allocation for simplicity, but that is just a detail:

```
Triangle t;           // default construct a Triangle object
IShape* myShape = &t; // IShape pointer points to a Triangle instance.
myShape->draw();      // calls Triangle::draw()
```

An example with dynamic allocation would be

```
std::unique_ptr<IShape> myShape(new Triangle());
myShape->draw();
```

Other issues:

1. Missing destructor implementation. Give `~IShape()` an empty body so derived classes aren't forced to implement a destructor when they don't need one.
2. Protected data can lead to confusing code. You should consider making `max_size` private.
3. Use the constructor initialization list to initialize data members rather than assign values to them in the constructor body: `Triangle() : max_size(255) {}`.

Comment: What's the difference of using constructor list or assigning a value inside?

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix In this case, the difference is only semantic because we're dealing with an `int`, so it doesn't matter too much. But when dealing with non built-in types, the semantic difference is important: when you assign a value, the object has to be default constructed first, then you perform an *assignment*, i.e. you change its value. When you initialize it in the initialization list, it gets constructed to have that value from the outset.

Answer (score 1):

This line is your problem:

```
IShape myShape = Triangle();
```

It creates a temporary `Triangle` object, and then tries to create an `IShape` object by copying the temporary triangle.  But `IShape` is abstract, you can't create such an object.

What you want is to have a handle to the `Triangle` object.  In C++, handles come in three kinds: references, pointers, and smart pointers.  Most of the time you should use a smart pointer.

Try this:

```
unique_ptr<IShape> myShape = new Triangle();
```

In Java, every variable with non-primitive type was automagically a handle to an object.  In C++, you can have both handles and actual objects stored in variables, so you need to tell the compiler when you intended to have a handle and which kind to use.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** It tells you so because you are declaring a real object, not a pointer to an object. Dynamic binding applies only to pointers to objects.

Let's see this:

```
IShape cShape = IShape();
Triangle cTriangle = Triangle();
```

Boths are syntactically correct, you are declaring objects with correct types. But you can't istantiate `IShape` because it's abstract.

```
IShape pShape = Triangle();
```

Syntactically correct but since `pShape` is concrete, the space for it is already reserved on stack, this means that everything in addition to what a `IShape` already is will be discarded and this ends up in [object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing). You can't use polymorphism with this situation.

```
IShape* pTriangle = new Triangle();
pTriangle->draw();
...
delete pTriangle;
```

Correct, you are declaring a pointer to a shape and initialize it with a dynamically allocated triangle instance. This is how it should be done and this is how it works in Java (when you just have references to objects).

**3)** You should never include a .cpp file indeed. You should move your `Triangle` class declaration from the `.cpp` to the `.h` file. Then it's your choice if to implement the body methods in the header file or create a `.cpp` file in which you implement Triangle `draw` method.

Comment: "a concrete object can't be initialized with a subtype"... false.  It usually shouldn't, because it causes slicing, but it can be done.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I specified what happens better.

Comment: @Jack: SO, you suggest that I move my Triangle.cpp inside IShape.h? I don't follow.

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix: Absolutely, but you can choose to keep your implementation in your .cpp file and just declare the class in the header file. You need to remove your Java kind of thinking. In C++ usually you have this redundancy just because you have separated compilation units.

Comment: @Jack: Don't take me wrong but I really think that is a terrible idea. Imagine that tomorrow I want to create an IShape that is a Circle, and then a Sqaure or something else. If I keep moving everything inside the IShape.h file I will end with a huge, monolithic beast !

Comment: No, because you should have `IShape.h`, `Triangle.h` and `Triangle.cpp`. Triangle.cpp includes `Triangle.h`, `Triangle.h` includes `IShape.h` and `main.cpp` includes `Triangle.h`.